# Flutter - How to conditionally add to or update an array in firestore?

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, crud

I am trying to add an element to an array in firestore if the array exists; otherwise, I need to create the array and then add the element to it.

```
        await workoutDoc
        .collection("exercises")
        .doc(exerciseId)
        .update({"sets": FieldValue.arrayUnion(sets)});
```

This code works fine if I have to update the existing array; how do I create one if none exists?

Tried this with merge - true and false.

```
 await workoutDoc
 .collection("exercises")
 .doc(exerciseId)
 .set(exercise, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

This just replaces the array element.

Answer (score 1):

Combine the two:

```
await workoutDoc
  .collection("exercises")
  .doc(exerciseId)
  .set("sets":  FieldValue.arrayUnion(<new element>), SetOptions(merge: true));
```